# Simplify $\sqrt{x^2-6x+9}-\sqrt{x^2+6x+9}$, if $x<0.$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, inequality, radicals

I realise that the radicands are perfect cubes and rewrite

$$\sqrt{(x-3)^2}-\sqrt{(x+3)^2}\Leftrightarrow|x-3|-|x+3|.$$ The possible answers are

a) $6$

b) $0$

c) $-12x$

d) None of the above is correct for all $x<0$.

The term $|x-3|$ tells me, geometrically, that $x$ is $3$ units away from $3$ on the $x$-axis and $|x+3|=|x-(-3)|$ tells me that $x$ is $-3$ units from the $x$-axis. Does this mean that we have $|x-3|-|x+3|=3-(-3)=6?$

Comment: Perfect *cubes*?

Comment: "The term |x−3| tells me, geometrically, that x is 3 units away from 3 on the x-axis"  Um...  does |2,519,517 - 3| tell you that $2,519,517$ is three units away for the $3$ on the x-axis?  If so, why?  |x -3| doesn't tell you anything in itself; it's a value without anything stated about the value.  |x-3| = k means that x is k units away from the 3.  But you aren't given |x-3| = 3.  You aren't given *anything* about |x-3|.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The three areas in question for this problem are $x\lt-3$, $-3\le x \le3$, and $x \gt 3$.

For $x\gt 3$
$$|x−3|−|x+3| = x-3 - (x+3) = -6$$
For $-3\le x \le3$
$$|x−3|−|x+3| =-(x-3)-(x+3) = -x+3-x-3 = -2x$$
For $x\lt-3$
$$|x−3|−|x+3| = -(x-3) - -(x+3) = -x + 3+x+3 = 6$$

Clearly, for $x \lt 0$, we have two equations, $y=-2x$ until $x=-3$ and $y = 6$ after $x=-3$. Therefore your answer is D.

Answer (score 5):

> I realise that the discriminants are perfect cubes and rewrite

Did you perhaps mean the *radicands* are perfect *squares*?

Anyway, since $x < 0$, then $x - 3 < -3 < 0$ and so $|x-3| = -(x-3) = 3 - x$ for all $x < 0$.

Also, $x + 3 < 3$, which means $x+3$ can be positive or negative (or zero).  So, $|x+3| = x+3$ if $-3 \le x < 0$, and $|x+3| = -(x+3) = -x-3$ if $x < -3$.

So we have two cases:

- If $-3 \le x < 0$, then $|x-3| - |x+3| = 3-x - (x+3) = 3-x-x-3 = -2x$.
- If $x < -3$, then $|x-3| - |x+3| = 3-x - (-x-3) = 3-x + x + 3 = 6$.

[View it on Desmos](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/dievpwqzb9)

Answer (score 3):

HINT: we have three cases:
1)$x\geq 3$ then we get $$x-3-x-3=-6$$
2) $$-3\le x<3$$ then we have $$-x+3-x-3=-2x$$
3) $$x<-3$$ then we get $$-x+3+x+3=6$$

Comment: You accidentally typed $-x + 3$ twice in your second case.

Comment: thanks just corrected!

Answer (score 3):

If $x<0$, then $x-3<0$ and therefore $|x-3|=-(x-3)=3-x$. If it turns out that $x+3<0$, then $|x+3|=-x-3$ and then $|x-3|-|x+3|=6$. But if $x+3>0$, then $|x+3|=x+3$ and, in this case, $|x-3|-|x+3|=-2x$.

Can we have $x<0$ and $x+3<0$? Yes: take $x=-4$. And can we have $x<0$ and $x+3>0$? Yes: take $x=-2$. Therefore, the answer is D.

Answer (score 2):

$\sqrt{(x-3)^2}-\sqrt{(x+3)^2}=|x-3|-|x+3|$

(*NOT* $\iff$...  The phrases $\sqrt{(x-3)^2}-\sqrt{(x+3)^2}$ as $|x-3|-|x+3|$ are not a sentences or a statements. They are simply values.  This doesn't make any more sense than $5 \iff 7-2$.  What *about* 5?  What about $7-2$?)

... and ....

$|x-3|-|x+3| = \pm (x-3) - \pm (x+3)$

Case 1:  $|x-3| = x -3$ and $|x+3| = x+3$.

That means $x-3 \ge 0$ and $x \ge 3 > 0$.  That's a contradiction this is not possible.

So $|x-3|-|x+3| \ne (x-3) - (x+3)$.

Case 2:  $|x-3| = x-3$ and $|x +3| = -(x+3)$.  That's a contradiction for the exact same reason.  $|x-3| \ne x -3$.

Case 3: $|x-3| = -(x-3)$ and $|x+3| = x+3$.

Then $x-3 < 0$ and $x < 3$.  That is true.  And $x+3 \ge 0$ so $x \ge -3$.  That is .... possible.  But not an absolute certainty.

***IF*** $-3 \le x < 0$ then $|x-3| -|x+3| = -(x-3) -(x+3) = -2x$.

But this might not be true if $x < -3$.

Case 4:  $|x-3| = -(x-3)$ and $|x+3| = -(x+3)$

If so then $x-3 < 0$ and $x < 3$ which is true.  $x+3 < 0$ and $x < -3$ which is possible.

***IF*** $x < -3$ then $|x-3| - |x+3| = -(x-3) -(-(x+3)) = (3-x) + (x+3) = 6$

...

So we have two possibilities.

Either $0 > x \ge -3$ and $|x-3| - |x+3| = -2x$.  OR. $x < -3$ and $|x-3| - |x+3| = 6$.

There is no single one answer for all $x < 0$.

So the answer is D.

====

Note if we didn't specify that $x < 0$ we'd have the possibilties that

If $0 \le x < 3$

The $|x-3| = -(x-3) = 3-x$ and $|x+3| = x+3$ so $|x-3| - |x+3| = (3-x)-(x+3)=-2x$

If $x \ge 3$ then $|x-3| - |x+3| = (x-3) - (x+3) = -6$.

So if we didn't have $x < 0$ we'd have three case.

If $x < -3$ then $|x-3| - |x+3|=6$.

If $-3 \le x \le 3$ then $|x-3| - |x+3|=-2x$.

And if $x > 3$ then $|x-3| - |x+3| = -6$.